# What is difference between Apache Subversion and TortoiseSVN/VisualSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, subversion-edge

I am new to setup/installation of subversion.

What I read is Apache Subversion is the main subversion development for the source code management.

Then there is VisualSVN/TortoiseSVN/WANdisco/CollabNet/SlikSVN for Windows given on below website :
https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Are these packages include Apache Subversion and we don't need to install separate Apache Subversion before installing these packages 
OR 
We need to install Apache subversion before installing these Server & Client packages of these packages ?

Comment: Did you read the manuals/ documentation on all of these sites? I am pretty sure that they state what is required to use any of them.

Comment: As per my information VisualSVN provides both subversion with some additional customized functionality on top of it. But I am not aware how exactly it provides the subversion core functionality of maintaining different code versions.                                                                                                                    For TortoiseSVN I have seen only Client version but I am not aware if it provides server functionality of maintaining code repositories.

Answer (score 1):

In case of VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN, you do not need to install Apache Subversion separately. I'm also pretty sure that you don't need to install Apache Subversion in other cases either.